# Change date format to yyyy/mm/dd in array and convert to json format

Tags: php, json, kohana

Here's my controller code:

```
$news = Model::factory('News')->get_all_news($user_id);   
$news->as_array();

foreach($news as $news):
    $sa[] = $news->as_array();
endforeach;

echo '{"news":'.json_encode($sa).'}';
```

Array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 32
                [created_date] => 2014-04-05 19:06:01
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
             ''''''''''
             ) 
     )
```

I am outputting the array in JSON format. I have lots of data in the array but I'd like to format just the date. Now I am getting the date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, but I want to format it like as `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:s` instead.

How can I do this? (preferably *before* encoding this array to JSON)

Comment: "*Is it possible before converting the array in json format.*" — Not unless you show us how you create the array in the first place.

Comment: if you can convert date format in database query, that would be more fast way..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to format the date

```
$date = new DateTime("2014-04-07 11:22:12");
echo $date->format("Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

And then push to json array or vise-versa

Side note :
If you have control over the query then you can do it directly on query. 
In Mysql it could be done using [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

So your query returned data will be in desired format and no need to do any further PHP operation.
Here is an example

```
select date_format(transdate,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s") as log_date  from log where idusers = 1 ;
+---------------------+
| log_date            |
+---------------------+
| 2013/05/13 00:00:00 |
| 2014/02/26 00:00:00 |
| 2014/02/26 00:00:00 |
| 2014/02/26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Already i am using a ORM query to select data from table,do i write a separate sub-query or select query.

Comment: well u do not need to write separate query, in the same query u can format the date field as above and the result set will have date data in the converted format.

Comment: I tried with date_format() in my query but it returns this error "Call to undefined method Model_News::date_format()".

Comment: hmm not sure how u are using it u may check the doc for ur ORM to see how to use date_format() in a query, the example I gave is for row sql query.